# durandal optimizer references wrong path when building it as a post build process in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, durandal

i set up a post-build event in visual studio to use durandal's optimizer (which uses nodejs) to build the main-built.js file for production. getting an error saying it can't find main-built.js. i believe this is because it's not referencing my project properly. my base directory is at c:\projects\myapp\myapp. it's only looking for the durandal directory from c:\projects\myapp.

is there a way to tell it the correct directory?

here's some of the output.

```
if 'Release'=='Release' C:\Projects\myapp\myapp\\App\durandal\amd\optimizer.exe
  Using default base configuration.
  Configuring for deploy with almond (custom).
  {
    "name": "durandal/amd/almond-custom",
    "inlineText": true,
    "stubModules": [
      "durandal/amd/text"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "text": "durandal/amd/text"
    },
    "baseUrl": "C:\\Projects\\myapp",
    "mainConfigFile": "C:\\Projects\\myapp\\main.js",
    "include": [
      "packages/Durandal.1.1.0/content/App/durandal/app",
         ...etc...
    ],
    "exclude": [],
    "keepBuildDir": true,
    "optimize": "uglify2",
    "out": "C:\\Projects\\myapp\\main-built.js",
    "pragmas": {
      "build": true
    },
    "wrap": true,
    "insertRequire": [
      "main"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I thought part of the point of serving out of an ASP.NET MVC project was the magic bundling and minification? (You know, all that stuff in the App_Start folder)

Comment: I suppose you're right. However, that's not the only reason i'm using asp.net mvc (simple security, etc). Also, the way durandal works with require.js is different than the way bundling works in asp.net. It has to do with pulling in the required files at run time when called upon, i think. You'd have to look at require.js to figure out all the advantages.

Comment: Yep ok. These are clashing strategies. If you bundle you get better compression. If you demand load you spread the delays and hide them behind human reaction and comprehension delays, providing the *perception* of better performance. I find that works well with small scripts whose dependencies are already met, and poorly with first loads of things like knockout-jqueryui which requires jQuery and knockout and jQuery UI. That's why I bundle the libraries but not the views. Don't forget that requirejs is partly about declaration of dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found out that even tho it's pointing to the wrong place, i can change it by using the --source attribute on optimizer.

the fix was to use the source attribute and point it to the base directory of the durandal files in the post-build event.

in my case, it looked like this:

```
if '$(Configuration)'=='Release' $(ProjectDir)\App\durandal\amd\optimizer.exe --source c:\projects\myapp\myapp\app
```

'app' being the root of the durandal files and folders.

Comment: thanks for this, I had just started thinking about this. one suggestion though. Use if '$(Configuration)'=='Release' $(ProjectDir)\App\durandal\amd\optimizer.exe --source $(ProjectDir)\App   as it wont matter where the project is located it should always work.