# Optimizing Durandal's build process

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, almond

The [HTML starter kit pro](https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/HTMLStarterKitPro) for Durandal contains the following grunt task for optimizing a build:

```
durandal: {
    main: {
        src: ['app/**/*.*', 'lib/durandal/**/*.js'],
        options: {
            name: '../lib/require/almond-custom',
            baseUrl: requireConfig.baseUrl,
            mainPath: 'app/main',
            paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { 
                'almond': '../lib/require/almond-custom.js' 
            }),
            exclude: [],
            optimize: 'none',
            out: 'build/app/main.js'
        }
    }
}
```

I have some concerns about it which I need your help sorting out:

1. Script file redundancy. The build process keeps the `lib` folder with scripts like jQuery, bootstrap etc. Why? If you look at the built `build/app/main.js` is has added all those scripts. Which leads me to the following question:
2. If I remove the `lib` folder, everything works, except for the fact that I get a `require is not defined` in the console. The code still looks for `lib/require/require.js` which can be solved by simply adding it there. However, isn't this what `almond` is all about? It's included in the built `build/app/main.js` file. As far as I knew, Almond is a light weight replacement for require to be used in optimized files.

To reproduce the issues you can simply run the "Quick start" provided in the link at the top.

Comment: may be this link helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684040/durandal-optimizer-references-wrong-path-when-building-it-as-a-post-build-proces

Comment: For your first concern, have you tried "removeCombined: true" property?

Comment: @nikhil Yes, it doesn't seem to have any effect though

Comment: I cloned your project and ran the "grunt durandal:main". In the build folder, only main.js file is getting created. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: You need to change the reference of the script file in your index.html to "build/app/main.js"

Comment: @nikhil My point is that third party libraries will exist both in the built `main.js` _and_ the `lib` folder when build is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You are right that `main.js` includes everything needed to run the app. The reason You are getting `require is not defined` is because, if you closely look at the `index.html` file you will see that the `index.html` refers looks for the file in `/lib/require` folder and loads our `main.js`  file through it. there is another line right below that in `index.html` which is commented, you can just uncomment that and it should just work even if you remove `lib` directory.

The only errros that you will get by removing the `/lib` directory after uncommenting `<script src="app/main.js"></script>` line and commenting `<script src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty obvious when you think of it. Thanks for a second set of eyes!